# Fastest way to fill an excel table

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a sub which will take data from one table (HeadsTable) and fill it into the appropriate place in another table (AllocatedHeads).  The HeadsTable contains headcount data by year.  These headcounts need to be split by a number of stakeholders and funding types.  The AllocatedHeads table will have a row for each stakeholder and funding type so one entry in the HeadsTable corresponds to multiple in the AllocatedHeads table(up to 30).  The headcounts themselves I am filling in with excel formulas, but I want the macro to fill in all of the decriptive data from the heads table.

I have created a HeadsEntry Class which holds all of the field data for an entry from HeadsTable and a HeadsCollection Class which is just a collection of all of the HeadsEntry Objects.

I am happy to show my entire sub, but what is shown here relates to my efforts to fill the table by iterating over the HeadsCollection.  The code below is functional, but takes a REALLY long time.  Hours.  My first attempt also worked and is shown in the comments.  It also took hours to run.

Is there a way I can accomplish this task in a more reasonable run time?

```
    Dim AbsRow As Long

    If [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        'clear table, add one row, get row value
        [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
        [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows.Add
        AbsRow = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows(1).Range.Row
    End If
    'dimension field column variables
    Dim DescriptionCol As Integer
    Dim LMWBSCol As Integer
    Dim Org1Col As Integer
    Dim Org2Col As Integer
    Dim Org3Col As Integer
    Dim PALS_OSsplitCol As Integer
    Dim ServiceShareRuleCol As Integer
    Dim Heads_IDCol As Integer
    Dim PALS_OSCol As Integer
    Dim ServiceCol As Integer

    'assign column values to variables
    DescriptionCol = [AllocatedHeads[Description]].Column
    LMWBSCol = [AllocatedHeads[LM WBS]].Column
    Org1Col = [AllocatedHeads[Org Tier 1]].Column
    Org2Col = [AllocatedHeads[Org Tier 2]].Column
    Org3Col = [AllocatedHeads[Org Tier 3]].Column
    PALS_OSsplitCol = [AllocatedHeads[PALS/O&S Split]].Column
    ServiceShareRuleCol = [AllocatedHeads[Service Share Rule]].Column
    Heads_IDCol = [AllocatedHeads[Heads_ID]].Column
    PALS_OSCol = [AllocatedHeads[PALS/O&S]].Column
    ServiceCol = [AllocatedHeads[Service]].Column

'    RowNum = 1
    For Each Entry In HeadsCollection.Entries
        For i = 1 To UBound(Entry.PALSOS)
            For j = 1 To UBound(Entry.Service)
'            [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows.Add
'            AbsRow = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows(RowNum).Range.Row
            Cells(AbsRow, DescriptionCol) = Entry.Description
            Cells(AbsRow, LMWBSCol) = Entry.LMWBS
            Cells(AbsRow, Org1Col) = Entry.Org1
            Cells(AbsRow, Org2Col) = Entry.Org2
            Cells(AbsRow, Org3Col) = Entry.Org3
            Cells(AbsRow, PALS_OSsplitCol) = Entry.PALSOSsplit
            Cells(AbsRow, ServiceShareRuleCol) = Entry.ServiceRule
            Cells(AbsRow, Heads_IDCol) = Entry.ID
            Cells(AbsRow, PALS_OSCol) = Entry.PALSOS(i - 1)
            Cells(AbsRow, ServiceCol) = Entry.Service(j - 1)
            AbsRow = AbsRow + 1
'            Set RowRange = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows(RowNum).Range
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Description]]) = Entry.Description
'            With Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[LM WBS]])
'            .value = Entry.LMWBS
'            .NumberFormat = "@"
'            End With
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Org Tier 1]]) = Entry.Org1
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Org Tier 2]]) = Entry.Org2
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Org Tier 3]]) = Entry.Org3
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[PALS/O&S Split]]) = Entry.PALSOSsplit
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Service Share Rule]]) = Entry.ServiceRule
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Heads_ID]]) = Entry.ID
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[PALS/O&S]]) = Entry.PALSOS(i - 1)
'            Intersect(RowRange, [AllocatedHeads[Service]]) = Entry.Service(j - 1)
'            RowNum = RowNum + 1
            Next j
        Next i
Next Entry
```

Comment: how many rows is there?

Comment: HeadsTable currently contains 175, producing a little over 4000 in the AllocatedHeads table.

Comment: I think a sample of data might help clarify exactly what it is you're doing here.

Comment: It will be **MUCH** faster if you write your table into an array that you have pre-dimensioned, and then write it to a worksheet range in a single step.  e.g: `ReDim V(1 to numrows, 1 to numcolumns)`; then fill in all the cells; then `Range(cell_ref).Resize(ubound(v,1),ubound(v,2)).Value = V`

Comment: This is a possibility.  I was hoping to make it so that the AllocatedHeads table columns do not have to be arranged the same way as the HeadsTable.  I don't think your solution allows for that, but it may be worth setting them up that way.

Comment: @DougClarke If you are responding to me, then read your original data into one VBA array; then create a different array to hold the results -- can be in whatever order you want; you may want to create a Class object and a collection to collect and massage the data; put the collection into the new array and write the results back to the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld.  That is probably faster, however I thought the code I posted in my answer was easier to implement based on what I had already done.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to convert to a range, fill in the cells, and convert back to a table.  Filling in cells in a range is MUCH quicker than in a table.  I also took advantage of the fact that filling in the first cell in a table column turns it into a calculated field.  By using formulas in those fields I reduced the number of fields I was storing in my Entry object and the number of cells I needed to fill in.  I am sure that there are much faster ways, but this solution brings it down from hours to under a minute, which is good enough for my needs.  The code beow doesn't show the entire sub, only the relevant portion.

```
    'determine needed size for Allocated heads table
        AllocatedHeadsRowCount = 0
        For Each Entry In HeadsCollection.Entries
        AllocatedHeadsRowCount = AllocatedHeadsRowCount + (UBound  (Entry.PALSOS) * UBound(Entry.Service))
        Next Entry

    'determine Absolute row (sheet row, instead of listobject row) of first row in table
    Dim AbsRow As Long
    AbsRow = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Row + 1

    'delete all table rows
    If [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        'clear table, add one row, get row value
        [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    End If

    'assign number values of header row, first table column, number of column
    AllocatedHeadsStartRow = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Row
    AllocatedHeadsStartColumn = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Column
    AllocatedNumberofColumns = [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count

    'dimension field column variables
    Dim Heads_IDCol As Integer
    Dim PALS_OSCol As Integer
    Dim ServiceCol As Integer

    'assign column values to variables
    Heads_IDCol = [AllocatedHeads[Heads_ID]].Column
    PALS_OSCol = [AllocatedHeads[PALS/O&S]].Column
    ServiceCol = [AllocatedHeads[Service]].Column

    'convert table to range because filling cells in a range is MUCH faster than in a table
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.Unlist

    'fill ID, PALS/O&S, and Service columns
    For Each Entry In HeadsCollection.Entries
        For i = 1 To UBound(Entry.PALSOS)
            For j = 1 To UBound(Entry.Service)
            Cells(AbsRow, Heads_IDCol) = Entry.ID
            Cells(AbsRow, PALS_OSCol) = Entry.PALSOS(i - 1)
            Cells(AbsRow, ServiceCol) = Entry.Service(j - 1)
            AbsRow = AbsRow + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    Next Entry

    'convert back to table
    With Sheets("Allocated Heads").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(AllocatedHeadsStartRow, AllocatedHeadsStartColumn), Cells(AllocatedHeadsStartRow + AllocatedHeadsRowCount, AllocatedHeadsStartColumn + AllocatedNumberofColumns - 1)), , xlYes)
    .Name = "AllocatedHeads"
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium7"
    End With

    'add formulas to the first cell in columns for which the data is the same as in the heads table.
    'This creates a calculated column and will fill down
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("Service Share Rule").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[Service Share Rule]:[Service Share Rule]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("PALS/O&S Split").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[PALS/O&S Split]:[PALS/O&S Split]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("Org Tier 1").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[Org Tier 1]:[Org Tier 1]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("Org Tier 2").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[Org Tier 2]:[Org Tier 2]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("Org Tier 3").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[Org Tier 3]:[Org Tier 3]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("LM WBS").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[LM WBS]:[LM WBS]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("Description").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[[Description]:[Description]])"
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("2009").DataBodyRange = "=LOOKUP(AllocatedHeads[@[Heads_ID]:[Heads_ID]],HeadsTable[[ID]:[ID]],HeadsTable[2009])*SUMPRODUCT((AllocatedHeads[@[PALS/O&S Split]:[PALS/O&S Split]] = SplitTable[[Split Name]:[Split Name]])*(AllocatedHeads[@[PALS/O&S]:[PALS/O&S]] = SplitTable[[PALS/O&S]:[PALS/O&S]])*SplitTable[2009])*SUMPRODUCT((AllocatedHeads[@[Service Share Rule]:[Service Share Rule]]=SplitTable[[Split Name]:[Split Name]])*(AllocatedHeads[@[Service]:[Service]]=SplitTable[[Service]:[Service]])*SplitTable[2009])"

    'Fill years columns by first drragging across(to have appropriate column references),
    'then copy pasting in place in order to create calculated columns
    Dim FirstCell As Range
    Dim FillRange As Range
    Set FirstCell = Intersect([AllocatedHeads].ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows(1), [AllocatedHeads[2009]])
    Set FillRange = Range(FirstCell.Address, Cells(FirstCell.Row, [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.Range.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column))
    FirstCell.AutoFill FillRange, xlFillDefault
    FillRange.Copy
    FirstCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

    'create calculated column in Total column
    [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.ListColumns("Total").DataBodyRange = "=SUM(" & FirstCell.Address(False, False) & ":" & Cells(FirstCell.Row, [AllocatedHeads].ListObject.Range.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column).Address(False, False) & ")"
```